# spawnSync /bin/sh ENOBUFS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Error "***spawnSync /bin/sh ENOBUFS***" spawns in my NodeJs application non-systematically while executing the following line :

```
child_process.execSync(`cd /tmp/myFolder ; tar -xjf myArchive.tar.bz2`);
```

Archive dimension is 81.5 MB, NodeJs version with NVM : 12.17.0.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that ***execSync*** mode execute the command within a shell with a limited buffer (200 Kb) used to forward the execution output. Moreover, the default shell execution option is "***pipe***", which means that the output must be forwarded to the parent.

In order to let the shell ignore the execution output, i.e. forward to /dev/null the output, and hence prevent the buffer from filling up, you must use the "***ignore***" execution option as following :

```
child_process.execSync(`cd /tmp/myFolder ; tar -xjf myArchive.tar.bz2`, { stdio: 'ignore' });
```

Read more about **exec** and **spawn** execution modes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698234/node-js-spawn-vs-execute) and [here](https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child-rocess.html)

**P.S.** Also consider that this error spawns **systematically**  when, during an archive extraction, you run out of disk space.

Comment: To add to this, if you would like to still capture the stdio for debugging instead of ignoring it entirely, you can simply redirect stdio to a file instead: `child_process.execSync('myscript.sh > myscript.log 2>&1');`

Answer (score 8):

### Use child_process.spawn if the output is important to you.

And even if you don't need it, execution output can be helpful when debugging. You can always add a simple switch which lets you silence the output should you choose.

I try not to use child_process.exec because child_process.spawn works just as fine but without the limitations of exec. *Of course, YMMV if your core application logic deals with streaming data.* The reason child_process.spawn will work here is because it streams output whereas child_process.exec buffers output and if you fill up the max buffer then child_process.exec will crash. You *could* increase the buffer size of child_process.exec via the options parameter but remember, the bigger the buffer, the more memory you use, whereas streaming usually keeps the memory usage to a minimum.

Here's a reference implementation. FYI, This code works on Node v14.

```
const child_process = require("child_process");

function spawn(instruction, spawnOpts = {}, silenceOutput = false) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let errorData = "";

        const [command, ...args] = instruction.split(/\s+/);

        if (process.env.DEBUG_COMMANDS === "true") {
            console.log(`Executing \`${instruction}\``);
            console.log("Command", command, "Args", args);
        }

        const spawnedProcess = child_process.spawn(command, args, spawnOpts);

        let data = "";

        spawnedProcess.on("message", console.log);

        spawnedProcess.stdout.on("data", chunk => {
            if (!silenceOutput) {
                console.log(chunk.toString());
            }

            data += chunk.toString();
        });

        spawnedProcess.stderr.on("data", chunk => {
            errorData += chunk.toString();
        });

        spawnedProcess.on("close", function(code) {
            if (code > 0) {
                return reject(new Error(`${errorData} (Failed Instruction: ${instruction})`));
            }

            resolve(data);
        });

        spawnedProcess.on("error", function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

// example usage
async function run() {
    await spawn("echo hello");
    await spawn("echo hello", {}, true);
    await spawn("echo hello", { cwd: "/" });
}

run();
```

Answer (score 2):

**`maxBuffer` to increase the buffer size**

As mentioned at: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processspawnsynccommand-args-options the default buffer is only 1024 * 1024 = 1M = 1048576 bytes long, which is relatively small for a modern computer memory. So if your stdout fits into memory, you could just increase that buffer size with something like:

```
child_process.spawnSync('printf', ['%1048577s'], { maxBuffer: 1048577 })
```

where the executable `printf` is used for the example because it prints n spaces when given a single argument `'%<n>s'` as mentioned at: [How can I repeat a character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash/5349796#5349796) making it easy to control the size of our stdout.

Minimal error reproduction if we go above the maximum buffer size by 1 byte:

```
const child_process = require('child_process')
const out = child_process.spawnSync('printf', ['%1048577s'])
console.log(out)
```

outputs:

```
{
  error: Error: spawnSync printf ENOBUFS
      at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1111:20)
      at Object.spawnSync (node:child_process:814:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ciro/tmp/main.js:4:27)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
      at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
    errno: -105,
    code: 'ENOBUFS',
    syscall: 'spawnSync printf',
    path: 'printf',
    spawnargs: [ '%1048577s' ]
  },
  status: 0,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    <Buffer 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ... 1048527 more bytes>,
    <Buffer >
  ],
  pid: 3166585,
  stdout: <Buffer 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ... 1048527 more bytes>,
  stderr: <Buffer >
}
```

and adding `maxBuffer` overcomes the issue.

Related:

- [Can someone explain an ENOBUFS error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679614/can-someone-explain-an-enobufs-error)
- [Very simple Node.js client throws error ENOBUFS after many http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603860/very-simple-node-js-client-throws-error-enobufs-after-many-http-requests)
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15617

**Read subprocess stdout line by line with `spawn` + `readline`**

This is a common use case. This pattern allows you to read a very large number of lines that might not fit into memory all together, so long as each line individually fits into memory.

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const childProcess = require('child_process')
const readline = require('readline')

const p = childProcess.spawn('./count.js', ['2'])
;(async function() {
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: p.stdout })
for await (const line of rl) {
  console.log('read: ' + line)
}
})()
```

Test helper:

count.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
(async function() {
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
let i = 0
let max
if (process.argv.length > 2) {
  max = parseInt(process.argv[2])
}
while (true) {
  console.log(i)
  if (i === max) break
  await sleep(1000)
  i++
}
})()
```

Output of `./main.js`:

```
read: 0
read: 1
read: 2
```

and each line appears one second after the previous one. Therefore we understand that this is reading lines immediately as soon as they become available as desired, and not waiting until the subprocess terminates to read everything at once.

Related: [Parse output of spawned node.js child process line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781214/parse-output-of-spawned-node-js-child-process-line-by-line)

Tested on Node.js v16.14.2, Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score -2):

### ENOBUFS means the process out size exceed so to fix this override process stdout here an example using nodejs:

```
            let ops={}
            ops.args=['logcat','-t',"'m-d h:min:s.000'"]
            //set output file
            ops.log='tmp/logfile.txt'
            largeout=run('adb.exe',ops) 
             console.log(largeout)

             //+++++++++++++++utils+++++++++++++++++++
            function run(cmd,ops={args:'',log:''}) {
            const{readFileSync,openSync}=require('fs');
            cmd=ops.args?cmd+" "+ops.args:cmd;    
            try{
            //override stdio[stdin,stdout,stderr]
            if(ops.log) {let log=openSync(ops.log,'w');ops.stdio=[null,log,log]}
            let rs= require('child_process').execSync(cmd,ops);
            //nb:ops.log:path file used to fix pipe size max 200k ENOBUFS;
            if(ops.log) rs=readFileSync(ops.log,'utf8'); 
            return !rs?false:rs.toString();
            }catch(e){
            console.log('ags.run err:',e.message);
            return false;
            }
            }
```